# After a Visual Studio 11 Ultimate beta Installation, I can't find the devenv.exe file

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2012

I've tried to search my question but I didn't find any question answered.

So, here is my problem:

I've installed the Visual Studio 11 Beta once, and it works perfectly. Then I uninstalled the Visual Studio 2010.

I don't remember why, but I had to reinstall VS11. After uninstalling it and installing again, I couldn't find the devenv.exe executable.

So I've tried to run Microsoft Blend, and then, create a project, but  I couldn't, because there was no templates available, neither a language to create the project.

When I try to search for Visual Studio in the start menu, I can't find it.

My English is not good, if you can understand, congratulations :D

Answer (score 0):

at this moment you should not longer install VS11.

you should download VS2012 as it is required to develop for win8 RP